# react component does not rerender after update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this react functional component where I have file input .
after I choose the file I assume the text in h1 tag should convert from
`choose file` to `test`  but nothing happen

- the handleChange function gets fired
- the console.log print state.show : true
- the INSIDE console.log() print state.show : true but does not show the string test

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default ({ selectedFile }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});

  const handleChange = e => {
    console.log('in handleChange');
    setState({ ...state, show: true });
  };
  console.log('My state: ', state);
  return (
    <div className='file-uploader'>
      <input type='file' id='upload' hidden onChange={handleChange} />
      <label htmlFor='upload'>
        {state.show ? <h1> {console.log('INSIDE ', state)} test</h1> : <h1>choose file</h1>}
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you try renaming state / setState? I don't think this would cause problems, but just in case there's some weird interaction between the legacy methods and the Hook usage.

Answer (score 1):

You need the following property `{show: false}` in your initial state.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default ({ selectedFile }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({show: false});

  const handleChange = e => {
    console.log('in handleChange');
    setState({ ...state, show: true });
  };
  console.log('My state: ', state);
  return (
    <div className='file-uploader'>
      <input type='file' id='upload' hidden onChange={handleChange} />
      <label htmlFor='upload'>
        {state.show ? <h1>test</h1> : <h1>choose file</h1>}
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-cdn-xspyk)

Comment: the demo is working even if you remove the initial value for {show:false} from the state.
but still not solve my problem

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary; undefined should resolve to false in the ternary.